# Pasar una variable a un modal - PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Estoy haciendo una consulta  a mi base de datos, de acuerdo a los resultados dados. me salen los libros con una descripción breve bibliográfica del libro , cuando le doy ver mas intento obtener esos mismos datos y aparte Extraer mas datos de mi Base. con base al Id de cada libro.

De esta forma es como se muestran los libros.

[image: Consulta búsqueda]

cuando le doy ver mas me sale unicamente el primer libro con su titulo, pero si le pongo en otro libro la información se sigue repitiendo

[image: Información Modal]

este es el código de la forma en que muestro la información breve
posteriormente ya haber hecho la conexión  y consulta.

```html
<div class="card-block">
                               <!--Text-->
                               <p class="card-text">
                                
                                <?php echo$fila["autor"] ?><br> 
                                 <?php echo$fila["editorial"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["idioma"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["ano"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["numeroPaginas"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["edicion"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["genero"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["isbn"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["ean"] ?><br>
                                 <?php echo$fila["formato"] ?><br>
                                 <?php $id = $fila["idlibros"]?>
                               </p>
                           </div>
```

Y así es como muestro la informacion en mi modal

```html
                           <!-- Button trigger modal -->
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="mimoda" id="milibro">
                             Ver mas 
                        </button>
                       
                        <!-- Modal -->
                        <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                          <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
                              <!--Content-->
                              <div class="modal-content">
                                  <!--Header-->
                                  <div class="modal-header">
                                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                      </button>
                                      <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">
                                      
                                           <?php echo$fila["nombre"] ?>
                                           
                                      <br></h4>
                                  </div>
                                  <!--Body-->
                                  <div class="modal-body">
                                    
                                  </div>
                                  <!--Footer-->
                                  <div class="modal-footer">
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
              
                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Comment: esto es algo que se basa en opiniones, lo que muestras en el codigo funciona correctamente?? donde esta el error que tienes??? no veo el metodo para obtener los datos nuevos...

Comment: <?php echo$fila["nombre"] ?> esto esta mal deberia de ser: <?=@$ListArray['i_txt_6']?>

Comment: ¿Cuántos modales tienes en tu página? ¿Tienen todos el mismo ID? Si ese es el caso, no importa en cuál de los botones pulses, siempre se abrirá el modal del primer elemento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para esto tienes 2 opciones:

1. Crear un modal para cada libro como dice @j0se.
2. Tener un único modal y modificarlo con `Javascript`, `JQuery`... Lo que uses.

Yo me decantaría por la segunda dado que si llegas a tener una página con 40 títulos, estaríamos hablando de 40 modales por página. Una barbaridad.

Al hacer "click" en cada "Ver más", modifica los datos del modal y luego muéstralo.

### EDIT

En caso de que quieras "extraer más datos" cada vez que pulsas "Ver más", deberías plantearte utilizar `Ajax`.

### EDIT 2

Revisa el comentario de Jakala, lo he estado probando y es interesante :)

Comment: Revisa como se hacen los modal en bootstrap, hay una opcion para los modal parametrizados. Mira este enlace: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-related-target, puede ayudarte. En tu caso, cada **data-wathever** podria contener el id del libro, y podrias añadir a mayores data-title, data-author... para luego leerlos directamente en el javascript y no tener que hacer un ajax de nuevo

Comment: Genial Jakala, no conocía esa opción. :)

Answer (score 0):

El id de **Ver mas** deberia de ser unico para cada libro podrias usar un

```
                        <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" name="mimoda" id="<?=$id?>_libro">
                         Ver mas 
                    </button>
```

Esto dentro de un bucle donde generas los libros, asi cada libro tendria su propio modal.

Edito: El data-target también debería ser único, tanto del boton como del modal

Answer (score 0):

esta es una solución si haces las peticiones a la db incrustadas en el php, otra solución seria una petición ajax, que te de como respuesta el array con la información que vas a mostrar y modificar la información desde jquery, algo que sería más practico.

```
            <div class="card-block">
            <!--Text-->
                <p class="card-text">
                    <?php

                        /*

                        .descripción{
                            padding-top: 10px;
                        }

                        */

                        //Conexión a db, llenar el array $fila

                        foreach ($fila as $object){
                            echo '<p class="descripción">' . $object . '</p>'; 
                        }

                    ?>
                </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Es necesario hacer un foreach para poblar la grilla de videos y un foreach para hacer tantos modales como videos existan, te dejo un ejemplo y te lo explico abajo:

```
/* Grilla de videos */    
<?php foreach ($crud->ListarVideo() as $r): ?>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
        <div class="portfolio-item thumbnail">
            <div class="hover-bg">
                <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?PHP echo $r->__GET('LinkNombre'); ?>" target="_new">
                    <div class="hover-text">
                        <h4><?PHP echo $r->__GET('Nombre'); ?></h4>
                        <small><?PHP echo $r->__GET('dato'); ?></small>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="img/comunidad/<?PHP echo $r->__GET('Imagen'); ?>" width="660" height="660" class="img-responsive" alt="<?PHP echo $r->__GET('Nombre'); ?>">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <!-------------------- MODALES -------------------------->

    <?php foreach ($crud->ListarVideo() as $r): ?>
    <div id="<?PHP echo $r->__GET('LinkNombre'); ?>" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

            <!-- Modal content-->
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Organización</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="well-sm">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                                            <img src="img/videos/<?PHP echo $r->__GET('Imagen'); ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?PHP echo $r->__GET('Nombre'); ?>">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
                                            <h4><?PHP echo $r->__GET('Nombre'); ?></h4>
                                            <h5><?PHP echo $r->__GET('Slogan'); ?></h5>
                                            <p>
                                                <?PHP echo $r->__GET('Texto'); ?></p>

                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i>
                                            <?PHP echo $r->__GET('Contacto'); ?>
                                            <br />
                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i>
                                            <?PHP echo $r->__GET('Fono'); ?>
                                            <br />

                                            <?php $url=$r->__GET('Web'); $www = str_replace('http://', '', $url); ?>

                                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i>
                                            <a href="<?PHP echo $r->__GET('Web'); ?>">
                                                <?PHP echo $www; ?>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Fijate que el nombre del modal es dinámico `id="<?PHP echo $r->__GET('LinkNombre'); ?>"` y que en la grilla de videos el link del modal es el mismo `<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#<?PHP echo $r->__GET('LinkNombre'); ?>" target="_new">` (lo que tu tienes como #myModal). Esto hace que puedas llamar a cada modal por separado. En este caso estoy utilizando PHP Orientado a objeto pero puedes hacerlo como quieras y funciona.